# How can I get value from observable

Tags: android, networking, kotlin, reactive-programming

I have this function in my Kotlin project. I'm using `ReactiveNetwork` -
 Android library listening network connection state and Internet connectivity with RxJava Observables. I'm new to reactive programming and now I need to refactor this method to use this in many places. How can I refactor this method to just return state of internet connectivity (isConnected)?

```
private fun downloadProductIfConnected(arguments: Bundle){
    ReactiveNetwork.checkInternetConnectivity().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe{ isConnected ->
                if (isConnected){
                    downloadAndOpenProduct(arguments)
                }else{
                    displayConnectionErrorDialog(arguments)
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: My advice would be to **not** use RxJava and this library if you want to return the result immediately. The library seems to notify you on changes. You want the current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can make use of **Higher-order functions** here, like below

```
private fun downloadProductIfConnected(callback:(Boolean)->Any){
  ReactiveNetwork.checkInternetConnectivity().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe{ isConnected -> callback(isConnected) }
    }
```

You can call like this

```
downloadProductIfConnected { isConnected-> onConnectionResult(isConnected) }


fun onConnectionResult(isConnected: Boolean){
    //do something with isConnected
}
```